# How to query estimatedGas for an ERC20 transaction?

Tags: contract-debugging, json-rpc, gas-estimate

This is the json-rpc call I make

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
  "method": "eth_estimateGas", 
  "params": [
   {
    "from": "0x71C7656EC7ab88b098defB751B7401B5f6d8976F", 
    "to": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7", //USDT
    "data": "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000044C004Fbbb407a45ea731AbE01E0CE348f311b9f000000000000000000000000000003e8" 
   }
  ],
  "id": "1"
}
```

but I keep on getting this error

```json
{ 
  "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
  "id": "1", 
  "error": {
     "code": "-32000", 
     "message": "execution reverted"
  }
}
```

The from address has enough USDT (around 10k USDT) and the value of the tx is 1000 USDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't encode the data correctly in the `value` params. It must be `uint256`.

So the correct payload should use this data string:

```json
"data": "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000044c004fbbb407a45ea731abe01e0ce348f311b9f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8"
```

Debugging Tips:

- Use [Tenderly transaction simulator](https://tenderly.co/transaction-simulator/) to simulate transaction to see which line it failed, or;
- Use [ABI decoder](https://www.moesif.com/solidity-abi-hex-decoder/decode) with `address` and `uint256` params to see what's wrong.